# Filter and search in jtable netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jtable

I still new in Java; I create one search or filter textfield to find my database in Jtable but this code only search a lowercase. How can I make this coding that can filter the lower and upper case?

Here is my code:

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
   DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.getModel();
      String search = jTextField1.getText().toLowerCase();
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
    JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.setRowSorter(tr);
    tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the given pattern by removing **toLowerCase()** method from the string

```
RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter =    RowFilter.regexFilter(Pattern.compile(lookup,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).toString(),0,1);
```

For further modifications follow the given link

https://coderanch.com/t/498043/java/JTable-rowFilter-case-insensitive

Comment: Miss, can you try modify my coding, i do not know how to change it

Answer (score 0):

Either you change your last line by this

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
   DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.getModel();
      String search = jTextField1.getText();
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new      TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
    JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.setRowSorter(tr);
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + "Alt",search));
 }
```

or

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
           DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.getModel();
              String search = jTextField1.getText();
            TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new      TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
            JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("alt",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE,search));
     }
```

or try this

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
   DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.getModel();
      String search = jTextField1.getText();
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new      TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
    JTable_MosqueManagementSystem.setRowSorter(tr);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("alt", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(pattern,search));
 }
```